# find videos with a minimum number of views with youtube api?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm wondering if there's any way to search for videos that only have x or more views.

I know I could return all results matching my query and simply filter through those that don't have enough, but that seems like a waste.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

It can filter the entries in the result set by ensuring that they match specific criteria. For example, you could use this parameter to specify that the API should only return entries for videos with more than 20 views, where the view count for each entry is identified in an XML element in the feed. In this case, the parameter does not necessarily affect the number of data fields that the API returns for an entry, but it can affect the number of entries actually returned.

```
   GET https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&max-results=10 \
       &fields=entry[yt:statistics/@viewCount > 1000000]
```

Comment: apologies, I actually didn't see that when looking through the docs somehow. thank you for the help though.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#Searching_for_Videos

I was looking at the custom query parameters and didn't see it there

Comment: accepted your answer, could you point me to where that part of the api is elaborated upon though? i'm having trouble finding it (the yt:statistics/@viewCount syntax)

Comment: Looks like simple logical operators. what is confusing about the syntax specifically?