# YouTube API get list of videos with more than n views

Tags: youtube-api

The title basically says it all.

Can I retrieve a list of videos with more than 1B views, using YouTube API?

I couldn't find anything like that in the official docs.

The same story for likes/dislikes. Sorta making a collection of most viewed/liked/disliked videos.

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331795/find-videos-with-a-minimum-number-of-views-with-youtube-api

Comment: It seems that this case implies a query. I need my query to be somewhat like `?viewsCount=gt1bil`

I am not looking for a particular topic of the video and filtering it by views. I am looking for let's call it `most popular videos ever`. Regardless of a topic.

I want to create a couple of playlists with music. Kinda like `songs what everyone already heard`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant specifflicly state that you want videos with over 1 billion views. However
[search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22order%22%3A%22viewCount%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D) does offer you the option to sort by view count.

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=viewCount&type=video&fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

This should return to you the videos with the highest count.

You can also sort by rating  which should be the likes.   YouTube removed public dislikes so i doubt this is something you would be able to sort on.

Unfortunately the YouTube Data api is very limited. This is going to be the best you can do.

Comment: i did run this exact request and the very first video in the response I had was a video with 50m views. And as you said YT API doesn't even offer this thing... eh